# vba FIND FUNCTION TO SELECT COPY/PASTE

Tags: vba, function, loops

I would like the code to look for a match. When a match is identified for it to see if other cells in the row meet a criteria. If yes, the to replace the criteria the match was run against with another cell In the match row

```
   Sub Find_sTRING()
        Dim AG_id As String, SNL_id As String, apd As String, spd As String, AQ As String, SQ As String
        Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long, AG_sht As Worksheet


        Dim x As Integer, j As Integer
        'For x = 1 To nrow
            'For j = 33 To ncol
                'c(x, j) = AG_sht.Cells(i, j).Value ''i * 2 + j ^ 2

        j = 6
        x = 3

        Set AG_sht = Sheets("AG")
        Dim rng As Range
        Lastrow = AG_sht.Range("B" & Sheets("AG").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To Lastrow
        AG_id = AG_sht.Cells(i, "AM").Value
        AQ = AG_sht.Cells(i, "E").Value
        apd = AG_sht.Cells(i, "F").Value
        If Trim(AG_id) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("SNL").Range("H:H")
                Set rng = .Find(What:=AG_id, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    Application.Goto rng, True 'value found
                    If rng(Rows, j).Value = AQ And rng(Rows, x).Value = apd Then
                        rng = AG_id
                    End If
                Else
                    i = i + 1
                End If
                If i = Lastrow Then
                Exit For

                End If
            End With
        End If
        Next
        End Sub
```

Comment: why did you post the code? .... what does it do?  .... what does it not do ?

Comment: @jsotola it finds the value but it does not allow me to extract another cell from the row

Comment: `it does not allow me to extract another cell` contains absolutely no information that can be used to solve a problem

Comment: @jsotola when the value is found I would like to select the row that the value is available.  This way I can retrieve other values in the row

Comment: still not enough information .... what is preventing you from selecting the row